# Bash, getting the latest folder based on its name which is a date

Tags: bash, directory

Can anyone tell me how to get the name of the latest folder based on its name which is formatted as a date, using bash. For example:

```
20161121/
20161128/
20161205/
20161212/
```

The output should be: 20161212

Comment: Pipe the output of `ls` (or `find`) to `sort` and then grab the last line. For example: `$ ls | sort | tail -n 1`

Comment: `ls -lth | head -1` can be used to sort based on the creation/modification of the file/folder

Answer (score 4):

Just use `GNU sort` with `-nr` flags for based on reverse numerical sort.

```
find . ! -path . -type d | sort -nr | head -1
```

An example structure, I have a list of following folders in my current path,

```
find . ! -path . -type d 
./20161121
./20161128
./20161205
./20161212
```

See how the `sort` picks up the folder you need,

```
find . ! -path . -type d | sort -nr
./20161212
./20161205
./20161128
./20161121
```

and `head -1` for first entry alone,

```
find . ! -path . -type d | sort -nr | head -1
./20161212
```

to store it in a variable, use command-substitution `$()` as

```
myLatestFolder=$(find . ! -path . -type d | sort -nr | head -1)
```

Comment: FWIW, most `sort` commands will support the `-n` and `-r` options, not just GNU.

Comment: Also, thank you for not parsing `ls`. +1 just for that. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Sorting everything seems like extra work if all you want is a single entry. It could especially be problematic if you need to sort a very large number of entries. Plus, you should note that `find`-based solutions will by default traverse subdirectories, which might or might not be what you're after.

```
$ shopt -s extglob
$ mkdir 20160110 20160612 20160614 20161120
$ printf '%d\n' 20+([0-9]) | awk '$1>d{d=$1} END{print d}'
20161120
$
```

While the pattern `20+([0-9])` doesn't *precisely* match dates (it's hard to validate dates without at least a couple of lines of code), we've at least got a bit of input validation via printf, and a simple "print the highest" awk one-liner to parse `printf`'s results.

Oh, also, this handles any directory entries that are named appropriately, and does not validate that they are themselves directories. That too would require either an extra test or a different tool.

One method to require items to be directories would be the use of a trailing slash:

```
$ touch 20161201
$ printf '%s\n' 20+([0-9])/ | awk '$1>d{d=$1} END{print d}'
20161120/
```

But that loses the input validation (the `%d` format for `printf`).

If you felt like it, you could build a full pattern for your directory names though:

```
$ dates='20[01][0-9][01][0-9][0-3][0-9]'
$ printf '%s\n' $dates/ | awk '$1>d{d=$1} END{print d}'
20161120/
```