# get maximum value of column

Tags: bash, sorting, awk

Hi i have a file like this (with n-lines):

```
0.001  5.4e+08 
0.03  0.08
0.5774  0.1
93  9832
```

now i want to read the maximum value of each column.
i tried awk like this:

```
awk -v "max=0.2" -v "index=1" 'BEGIN{if (index>max) max=index} END {print max}' file
```

and asign the output to a variable.
Only typing the awk command in the shell gives me this error:

```
awk: run time error: cannot command line assign to index
    type clash or keyword
    FILENAME="" FNR=0 NR=0
```

The Problem is that the file has n-lines and i am only looping over certain lines.
How can i give awk the line to work on and read out the maximum value of the column of that line?

Comment: it does, the solution was that i shouldnt use "index" as a variable name

Comment: You should mention this specific constraint as part of the question, without it, the problem is an exact duplicate.

Comment: Aside from the syntax issues, this was literally the last question I answered, over [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41202447/1072112).

Answer (score 5):

`index()` is the name of an awk function, pick a different variable name like `idx`.

Also, to print the max value of an "index" you don't need to seed the max with some ad-hoc value, it would just be:

```
$ awk -v idx=1 'NR==1 || $idx>max{max=$idx} END{print max}' file
93
```

Comment: okay but if i do:


awk -v "max=0.001" -v "idx=1" 'BEGIN{if ($idx>max) max=$idx} END {print max}' CH4_p01a00242tf0300to0300.kg

my output is:0.001 whilst it should be 93

Comment: Well, yeah, you've stuck your computation in a BEGIN section which is executed before your input file is opened so what you get in the END is what you had before you started.

Comment: now i know what to use BEGIN and END for, thank you for the help!

Comment: @EdMorton - also, you don't need to set `max` on `NR==1` either, as long as `$1` will be positive. An uninitialized variable evaluates as zero. `awk 'BEGIN{if(1>a)print"foo";if(a>1)print"bar"}'` returns only `foo`.

Comment: @ghoti When doing min/max calculations you should always init using the first value read rather than some ad-hoc value you assume/hope will be less/more than the max/min in the data. It's much more robust and has close to zero overhead in code or performance. Uninitialized variables have the value `zero-or-null`, btw, since their type is `numeric-string`, assuming it'll be `zero` (or `null`) can cause problems.